# Java: Find index of integer with maximum value (all method arguments)

Tags: java, return

I am trying to write a method which has 3 input arguments (all of which are integers). I want the method to determine which of the 3 input values is the largest, after this the method should return the index of this largest number.

If no maximum is found (in case all input arguments are the same) the method should return the value -1 .

I have written this using an if, else if, else loop but it (my method) keeps returning the wrong value and I don't know why.

```
public class testingmybig{
int num1 = 9;
int num2 = 2;
int num3 = 3;

    public static int main(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
        int value = 0;
        System.out.printf("Num1 = % , Num2 = % , Num3 = % \n", num1, num2, num3);

        if ((num1 > num2) && (num1 > num3)) {
            System.out.println("number 1 is largest");
            value = 1 ;
        }else if ((num2 > num1) && (num2 > num3)){
            System.out.println("number 2 is largest");
            value = 2 ;
        }else if ((num3 > num1) && (num3 > num2)){
            System.out.println("number 3 is largest");
            value = 3 ; 
        }else{
            System.out.println("All numbers are equal");
            value = -1 ;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

At the moment my code prints out "number 3 is largest" whilst what it should do is evaluate the code inside the iff statement and print "number 1 is the largest" (since num1=9 has the largest value of the 3 numbers)...

Any help will be greatly appreciated, than you very much! :)

Comment: The instance variables you declared have nothing to do with the arguments to `main`. How are you calling `main`?

Comment: Nope. That code will print "number 1 is largest" like it's supposed to for those values of num1-3. You should construct and post a [mcve] which reproduces your problem (it's currently not minimal, complete nor verifiable). Also, don't name your method `main`, that's just confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will do that (post minimal,complete,verifiable example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public static int largest(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    if (num1 == num2 && num2 == num3) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return Math.max(Math.max(num1, num2), num3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)